# Use ASP.Net Core 2 Identity with Azure Ad single tenant authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, azure-active-directory

I would like to get help from community for one problem that I don't understand.
I create asp.net core 2 web application and I would like to configure the app to be able to **login from the app** via aspnetuser table or by using **O365 Company account**.
Then I followed multiple techniques described on the web included on MSDN website.
The app authentication works fine but Azure add returned : **Error loading external login information.**
I checked inside the code by generating identity views, the app failed on:

```
 var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (info == null)
        {
            ErrorMessage = "Error loading external login information.";
            return RedirectToPage("./Login", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
        }
```

await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync(); return null and return the error message.

The application is correctly configured in azure AD and it work from my app if I remove the authentication from the app.

I configured my app middlewares as follow:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie()
            .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
        services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
        {
            options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/";
            options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = true;
        });
```

And in configure method I added

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

When I arrive on my login screen app (scaffolded by VS) all seems correct:

Login screen with two possibilities for authentication]:

[image: Login screen with two possibilities for authentication]

Error message when i try Azure Active Directory method:

[image: Error message when i try Azure Active Directory method]

Can someone explain and help me to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, little update concerning my post. After some multiple test i found the solution. I don't know if it's the best but it's working fine in my side. I implemented all AzureAd classes for authentication in my own project without using the provided stuff from .Net core to handle it. Hope will be fixed in next release maybe...

Comment: I have the same issue using .NET Core 3.1
Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

The solution is to add cookieschemename as externalscheme. Below is sample code block in Startup.cs file.

```
 services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddAzureAD(options => { Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options); options.CookieSchemeName = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme; });
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately I had more or less the exact same problem. Although [the Azure sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2) worked on its own, when I tried to integrate it to an existing application that uses Identity and other external authentication services, I could not get AzureAD to work. The interesting thing is that although in the output window I could see logging messages saying that the login was accomplished.

What I did (and this is more of a workaround rather than an exact solution to the problem) was to abandon using the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI package and I opted to go the longer way and configure OpenID manually for Azure. [This](https://joonasw.net/view/aspnet-core-2-azure-ad-authentication) article helped me immensely towards that end.

Having said that, I hope someone posts a more direct answer to your question.