# AzureAD not working with IdentityUser and IdentityRole

Tags: .net, azure-active-directory, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm trying to get AzureAD authentication implemented in my app, which has role authentication. When I try to run the app, instead of automatically going to Microsoft login page (like it does in new project made apps), it goes to login page, with an option to use Azure Active Directory, when clicked on, it throws  `Error loading external login information.` and nothing happens.

After tinkering with it for a bit, I've noticed that if I remove this line of code

`services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>().AddRoles<IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();`

from `ConfigureServices` in `Startup.cs`, it starts working again.

What is it about that line of code that interferes with AzureAD?

Comment: Could you show the code where you configure AAD?

Answer (score 0):

This line of code add [ASP.Net Core Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) in the DI. And tells it to use the `ApplicationDbContext` to store its users and roles.

Comment: Right, i know that, so how does it interfere with AzureAD?

Comment: AzureAD is then used as an external provider for the authentication

Comment: Is there a way to use both?

Comment: Yes, but the configuration is not the same

Comment: Check your callback URLs in AzureAD

Comment: Can you give examples of what the configuration might be? Or at least where to look for solutions?

Comment: This article should help I guess : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: I've applied the solution, but it's the same problem, except i don't get the error anymore.

Comment: Is this answer help ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/59749884/2940908

Answer (score 0):

With the codes you are adding the ASP.NET Core Identity into your application , and Azure AD is one of the external authentication providers.

In that scenario , you can set `CookieSchemeName` to `Identity.External` so that asp.net core identity can get the external user profile from external identity provider :

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "xxx.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "xxx-a2dd-4fde-bf8f-f75ab18b21ac",
    "ClientId": "xxxxx-9f22-4c88-aafb-fe00a30caa78",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "CookieSchemeName": "Identity.External"
},
```

After authentication , by default , asp.net core identity will create a local account that associates your external account , so that you can perform authorization with your local identity system .